# Window.locatin preventing data from deleting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have a button that, when pressed, I want to delete the object. Here is my button:

```
<Button onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this)}> 
    Delete 
</Button>
```

And here is my `handleDelete`:

```
handleDelete() {
    axios
      .delete(
        `http://proiectdepozite.laravel/api/clienti/${this.state.client.id}`
      )
      .then((window.location = "/clienti"))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

Now, if i press the button, it will redirect me where i want to, but it won't delete anything. I tried commenting out `.then(....)` and it works as it should. Where is the mistake?

Comment: Your JS syntax. `then` expects a function. Look at your console.

Comment: try like this axios.delete('url', { data: payload }).then(
  // Observe the data keyword this time. Very important
  // payload is the request body
  // Do something
)

Comment: I see no errors in my console...

Comment: @DariusBiro Hm, weird. But still, `then` expects a function. I guess an expression is valid syntax, but wrong.

Comment: @abhinavxeon Maybe, but there's a more-glaring issue. Sending just a URL should be sufficient (if that's how the API works).

Comment: I suspect the redirect happens before the request goes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.then method need callback function but you just pass some expression.

```
handleDelete() {
    axios
      .delete(
        `http://proiectdepozite.laravel/api/clienti/${this.state.client.id}`
      )
      //try this
      .then(()=>(window.location = "/clienti"))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
```

```
//use async await
async handleDelete() {
   try{
    let result = await axios.delete(
       `http://proiectdepozite.laravel/api/clienti/${this.state.client.id}`
      )

     if(result){
       //success logic 
       window.location = "/clienti"
     }

  }
  catch(e){
    throw e;
  }
}
```

Comment: The first method worked. Thank you! Is there any reason that I should use the second one over the first one?

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks!

Comment: Noting that "easier to read and scale" is a matter of opinion. I find the first one easier--a single async request isn't difficult to reason about.

Answer (score 2):

```
axios.delete('url', { data: payload }).then(
  // Observe the data keyword  Very important
  // payload is the request body

   ()=>(window.location = "/clienti")//you can pass as pipe function


)
```

Comment: It's only very important if you have data to send--the only *required* parameter is the URL.